# colour of glossaryentry name in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, color, glossaries

Currently, I am trying to change the colour of the name of a glossaryentry within my beamer presentation

`\setbeamertemplate{glossary name}` does not work. What can I do?.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal document to illustrate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}[t, allowframebreaks, label=Glossar]
   \frametitle{Glossar}

   \setbeamercolor{description item}{fg = Red}

   \printglossary
\end{frame}
```

Glossary entries seem to be typeset by using the **description** environment Thus setting the colour of the **description item** works for me.